# Why is instance variable behaving like a class variable in Python?

Tags: python, class, variables, instance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I have the following code:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value = 0, children = {}):
        self.val = value
        self.children = children

    def setChildValue(self, index, childValue):
        self.children[index] = Node(childValue)

n = Node()
n.setChildValue(0,10)
print n.children
n2 = Node()
print n2.children
```

And it prints:

```
{0: <__main__.Node object at 0x10586de90>}
{0: <__main__.Node object at 0x10586de90>}
```

So my question is, why is children defined in n2? Children is an instance variable and yet it's acting like a class variable.

Thanks

Comment: it's called [least astonishment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 4):

You're assigning the same dictionary to `children` on every instance.

Answer (score 2):

When you define the function `__init__` you give it a dictionary as a default argument. That dictionary is created once (when you define the function) and then used every time `__init__` is called.

More information:
http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in Martijn's comment and kindall's answer, you are running into the mutable default argument behavior which bites most Python developers at some point, here is how you can modify `Node.__init__()` so that it works the way you expect:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, value = 0, children = None):
        self.val = value
        if children is None:
            self.children = {}
        else:
            self.children = children
```