# python object instance variable looks like a class variable?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using `SQLAlchemy` in Python 3 and am confused why the following code works - it looks to me like what should be an object level variable is acting as a class variable. I have seen [Why is instance variable behaving like a class variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144433/why-is-instance-variable-behaving-like-a-class-variable-in-python) which doesn't look related to my question.

I have the following declarations in a `db` module in which I create an instance of `Base` and set a `query` variable on it that points to the `SessionFactory` `query_property()`

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as sa_ed


Base = sa_ed.declarative_base()
engine = sa.create_engine('connection string')
session_factory = session or sa_orm.scoped_session(sa_orm.sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))
Base.query = session_factory.query_property()  # make the query_property available in models for querying
```

My model classes are then declared as follows:

```
import db

class MyModel(db.Base):
    id = Column(Integer)
    # more model stuff
```

I can then run queries by accessing the `query` variable as follows:

```
return MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.id == 22).first()
```

This does work, but it looks as though the `query` variable exists at the class level and not at the object instance level as I am able to access it directly through the class.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why you would be expecting `query` to _not_ be at the class level ... Perhaps you can edit your post and explain that better?

Comment: I thought that `Base = sa_ed.declarative_base()` was creating an instance of the `Base` class I.e. an object of type `Base`. I see now that it is creating a class, which makes more sense

Comment: Ahh ... Yes, I suppose that would make for some confusion.  It's a somewhat abnormal pattern to return a class from a function (rather than a class instance), but it is definitely useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the `query` property on the parent class earlier:

```
Base.query = session_factory.query_property()  # make the query_property available in models for querying
```

So `query` is most definitely a member of *a* class (`Base`).  And since `MyModel` inherits from `Base`, `MyModel` should also have a `query` member (due to the magic of inheritance).

Comment: Ah okay, so `Base` is a class not an object! I assumed by doing `Base = sa_ed.declarative_base()` I was creating an instance of the `Base` class i.e. a `Base` object. Looking at how I use `Base` I can see it would make more sense to be of type class